# How to properly interact with Resources from a Fragment

Tags: android, android-resources

My question is more related to good practices to follow, the code I made is working but I am not sure if I am doing the following the right way.

This is the current version of a simple Fragment that is used inside a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`, meaning the fragment can be called hundreds of times while the app is used.

Basically I declared a class variable to handle the `Resources` this way:

```
public class RateFragment extends Fragment {

    private DatabaseHandler db;
    private Resources resources;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        // Getting the maximum number of days
        db = new DatabaseHandler(this.getActivity());
        resources = this.getResources();
```

In the rest of the class, I just get the resources needed by doing for example: `resources.getString(R.string.hello)`.

Is it a bad idea and why exactly? Do I have to switch to `getResources()` everywhere?

Little additional question: is there a difference here between `getResources()` and `this.getResources()`?

Thanks!

Comment: calling getResources() or this.getResources() withen the class that extends fragement is the same, one is implicitly and one explicitly.

Comment: To begin with, you definitly should not use getActivity in onCreate() in a fragment. The reason : the activity is not inevitably created. This can makes your application crash. You may have a context variable that you assign only at the good time, during the life time of the parent activity and not each time you need it ;)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I realize I did that in several places, by any chance do you have any example to see how to fix that?